# bad_header for AMQP connection while connecting sensu-client to server

Tags: rabbitmq, chef-infra, amqp, sensu

I have installed sensu with chef community cookbook. However, sensu client fails to connect to server. Results in rabbitmq connection error with message timed out while attempting to connect

Here are detailed client logs

logs from sensu-client.log

```
"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:33.982647+0000","level":"warn","message":"config file applied changes","config_file":"/etc/sensu/conf.d/config.json","changes":{"rabbitmq":{"heartbeat":[null,20]},"client":[null,{"name":"girija-sensu-client","address":"test sensu client","subscriptions":["test-node"]}],"version":[null,"0.12.6-4"]}}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:33.996680+0000","level":"info","message":"loaded extension","type":"mutator","name":"only_check_output","description":"returns check output"}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:34.000721+0000","level":"info","message":"loaded extension","type":"handler","name":"debug","description":"outputs json event data"}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:34.104300+0000","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to rabbitmq"}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:39.108623+0000","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to rabbitmq"}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:44.111818+0000","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to rabbitmq"}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:49.115250+0000","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to rabbitmq"}
{"timestamp":"2014-07-08T12:39:54.045648+0000","level":"fatal","message":"rabbitmq connection error","error":"timed out while attempting to connect"}
```

Rabbitmq logs from server show following error

```
=INFO REPORT==== 8-Jul-2014::12:39:54 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.395.0> (10.254.153.131:42813 -> 10.254.130.25:5672)

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Jul-2014::12:39:54 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.395.0> (10.254.153.131:42813 -> 10.254.130.25:5672):
{bad_header,<<129,15,1,3,3,0,246,0>>}
```

I am running this on CentOS 6.4 on AWS
Rabbitmq version 3.0.4
Erlang_version,
     "Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},

bad_header suggests mismatch for client and broker AMQP version. Any help for finding out AMQP version and  fixing this problem

Answer (score 9):

This issue was caused, in my case, when my client was configured to use ssl authentication, but the rabbitmq server was not properly configured to use ssl and instead was expecting "plain" user/pass login with no ssl.

Comment: I had the opposite problem -- my /etc/config.json specified use of the plaintext port when the rabbit server was configured to only use SSL.  Changing the port setting got the Sensu client working again.