# bad header response from rabbitmq when trying to make a connection

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have two containers running to simulate a broker and a sub using python with poho, and using rabbitmq as a broker.

When I try to make a connection with python as in the following example.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("s/temp")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))


client = mqtt.Client(clean_session=True, userdata=None)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("rabbitmq", port=5672, keepalive=60, bind_address="")
client.loop_forever()
```

I get an error from rabbitmq saying

```
rabbitmq  | 2021-05-05 02:57:43.478 [info] <0.1436.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1436.0> (172.28.0.3:57387 -> 172.28.0.2:5672)
rabbitmq  | 2021-05-05 02:57:43.479 [error] <0.1436.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1436.0> (172.28.0.3:57387 -> 172.28.0.2:5672):
rabbitmq  | {bad_header,<<16,12,0,4,77,81,84,84>>}
rabbitmq  | 2021-05-05 02:57:43.481 [info] <0.1438.0> Closing all channels from connection '172.28.0.3:57387 -> 172.28.0.2:5672' because it has been closed
```

for running the containers I am using the following docker-compose

```
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - pubsub

  api:
    build: .
    container_name: "fastapi"
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    networks:
      - pubsub

networks:
  pubsub:
    driver: bridge
```

I tried to run it locally but I got the same error, and see some blogs and [see other stackoverflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632563/bad-header-for-amqp-connection-while-connecting-sensu-client-to-server) and don't find the answear

Answer (score 2):

If you're connecting using the MQTT protocol, RabbitMQ:s default ports are 1883 and 8883(TLS). Maybe this could be the issue?

Comment: Thanks seriously for helping me, I've been looking all day to see what it was, I solved it by running the command rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt